# Why won't the code display a number?

Tags: javascript

The code works when instead of document.write(total); I write ex:

```
document.write((a*b)/(c*d)+"<br>");
```

this problem has occurred a lot in my recent projects while trying to learn this language

```
function calc(){ 
    for(x = 0; x < 5; x++){

    var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1) ;
    var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1) ;
    var c = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1) ;
    var d = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1) ; 
    var total += (a * b) / (c * d)  ;          

    document.write(total);
}
```

Comment: Initialize total outside of the scope of your for loop and then reference it as total += instead of var total +=.  Right now you are attempting to add to an uninitiailzed variable of total so it will never receive a value

Answer (score 3):

Because your `total` was undefined at the time you did an **increment-assignement** (`+=`) to it

it should be

```
var total = (a*b)/(c*d);
```

or your `total` variable should be declared outside the `for-loop`

```
function calc() {
  var total = 0;
  for (x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
    var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
    var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
    var c = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
    var d = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
    total += (a * b) / (c * d);
    document.write(total);
  }
}
```